Cpanel React js dynamic site not running
I am trying to run my dynamic node react js web app on cpanel. But as I try and 'run js script' of npm run dev I get this error message...
returncode: 1stdout:


vite-project@0.0.0 dev /home/vipempao/public_html/topDatavitestderr:npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/vipempao/nodevenv/public_html/topData/10/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the --scripts-prepend-node-path option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with./home/vipempao/nodevenv/public_html/topData/10/lib/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:2import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'^


SyntaxError: Unexpected token {at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLEnpm ERR! errno 1npm ERR! vite-project@0.0.0 dev: vitenpm ERR! Exit status 1npm ERR!npm ERR! Failed at the vite-project@0.0.0 dev script.npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     /home/vipempao/.npm/_logs/2024-10-15T23_49_16_088Z-debug.log

Ive tried every version of npm run, and it continues to give me the same error
